# what is the exact difference between mongoDb compass and robo3T

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass, robo3t

I'm a novice in mongoDb concept and my senior has advised me to get my hands dirty on mondoDB compass and robo3T but I'm pretty confused in these two, everywhere I see mongoDB atlas and not compass. Can someone please explain me in an easier way .

Comment: Hovering over the tags, you can see, _"mongodb-atlas": "MongoDB Atlas is a cloud database service for running, monitoring, and maintaining MongoDB deployments, including the provisioning of dedicated servers for the MongoDB instances."_  Practically, you can instantiate your own MongoDB Atlas cluster (for free!) and access/use it from Atlas's web interface, MongoDB Compass, and/or Robo3T ... and easily from any of the many [MongoDB drivers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/) and derivatives.  Perhaps you've been advised to create you own cluster, use example DBs, and try the apps.